# Translate Code Snippet from C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-translation

I need to translate line 4 in the code snippet below into VB. For some reason I cannot get this done tonight. I am either too tired or having a brain drain...  Can you help?

```
var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
provider.ClientIdentifier = ClientCredentials.ClientID;
provider.ClientSecret = ClientCredentials.ClientSecret;
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthentication);
```

Translation tools have gotten me this far, but it's not right.

```
Dim provider As NativeApplicationClient = New NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
provider.ClientIdentifier = ClientCredentials.ClientID
provider.ClientSecret = ClientCredentials.ClientSecret
Dim auth As OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient) = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, GetAuthorization)
```

The GetAuthorization method has the following signature.

```
Private Function GetAuthorization(ByVal arg As NativeApplicationClient) As IAuthorizationState
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `AddressOf`

```
Dim auth As OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient) = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, AddressOf GetAuthorization)
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. :D  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [Website](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/#convert-code) for the Translation of any code from C# to VB
 and the code after conversion is

```
Dim provider = New NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
provider.ClientIdentifier = ClientCredentials.ClientID
provider.ClientSecret = ClientCredentials.ClientSecret
Dim auth = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, GetAuthentication)
```

Comment: The DownVoters should say a Reason why?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use OAuth2Authenticator to GetAuthorization and the two are different, maybe that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

AddressOf never calls the function, you need to use

```
Dim getAuth As Func(Of NativeApplicationClient, IAuthorizationState) = AddressOf GetAuthorization
Dim auth As New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, getAuth)
```